# React.MouseEvent vs React.MouseEvent<HTMLAnchorElement, MouseEvent> in TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Ive added a type to a anchor click event in React based on the TypeScript error that I got when it was untyped:

```
onClick={(event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLAnchorElement, MouseEvent>) => {
  event.preventDefault();
}}
```

I still don't get errors if go with this shorter version:

```
onClick={(event: React.MouseEvent) => {
  event.preventDefault();
}}
```

Is the second version less type safe? What am I giving up in a practical sense?

Answer (score 1):

MouseEvent interface:

```js
interface MouseEvent<T = Element, E = NativeMouseEvent> extends UIEvent<T, E> {
 // ...
}
```

You dont' need to pass the second generic type. So this way will solve the error:

```js
onClick={(event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLAnchorElement>) => {
  event.preventDefault();
}}
```

Comment: What type safety does this give you that just using React.MouseEvent wouldnt?